# jquery .live( ) passing argument

Tags: jquery

I want to pass the width and height parameter to the .live() function. It works but it does not see (this) tag. Shortly, is it possible to pass value to the live function in jquery?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? .live is deprecated in the most recent version.

Also, can we see some code?

Comment: Could you also explain your question in a little more detail?  What are you trying to achieve?  Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: it is recommended to you .On() instead of .live()

Comment: I used .on but it works for only first click. in tehe second click it does not open the pop up but it redirects the page.

Comment: I am using jquery ui to show an aspx page as a pop up. I have more then one pop up. therefore I want to pass width and height parameters with the "e" parameter.

Comment: this is the code:  $('a#popup').live('click', function (e ) { popupAc(e, 500,500) });

Comment: If our answers didn't solve you problem, please put your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).on('.yourElement', 'event', function() {
    var height = 800;
    var width = 400;
    jQuery(this).height(height);
    jQuery(this).width(width);
});
```

or if you want to you live:

```
jQuery('.yourElement').live('click', function(){
    var height = 800;
    var width = 400;
    jQuery(this).height(height);
    jQuery(this).width(width);
});
```

If you don't want to use on I recommend [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
jQuery(document).delegate('.yourElement', 'click', function(){
    var height = 800;
    var width = 400;
    jQuery(this).height(height);
    jQuery(this).width(width);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to get the width and height properties. I want to set them.

Comment: So you can use the same function( height or width) to set the value, just passing thrue the parameter, my answer was updated with the code.

Answer (score 1):

it is not posible, but inside the function you have access to `this` instance which will be the html element that triggered the event:

```
    $("#element").live("click", function(){
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
    })
```

it would be the same using on() since as @FAddel says it is now the recommended way

```
    $("#element").on("click", function(){
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
    })
```

Comment: this is my code:  $('a#popup').live('click', function (e ) { popupAc(e, 500,500) });
            $('a#popup2').live('click', function (e) { popupAc(e, 200, 200) });

Comment: the twoo 500,500 are the width and height parameters to set the width and height of the popup created by popupAc function

Comment: you cannot send parameters, but probably theres a way to get those numbers inside the function.. are 500,500 fixed or calculated? if calculated can you do that calculation inside the function?

Comment: They are calculated. That is, I try the width and height of the pop up, if they fit the size I want to send the value to the function.

Comment: the easiest way then is calculate that inside you function, give it a try it should be possible